# How to add elements from an array in to echarts tooptip?

Tags: echarts

suppose I have entity_name = ['www','eee']
I want to add an Entity name into tooltip after the seriesName, which comes from the entity_name array and needs to be added sequentially, one dot for each seriesName and for each Entity name.

I have tried:

```
formatter: function (obj) { 
var value = obj.value; 
var a = ''; 
for(var i = 0; i< 2;i++){ 

a += '<div>'+ obj.seriesName + entitiy[i]+'</div>' 
} 
return a;
```

but all of the entity names are added.

Comment: we need more context to help you, more code please, the entity is not defined here?

Comment: entity_name = ['www','eee']

Answer (score 0):

In the tooltip formatter function you can iterate through your entity variables. See example below:

```
const entityNames = ['www', 'eee'];
var option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: params => {
            const {seriesName, value} = params;
            let template = 'Tooltip: <br >';
            
            entityNames.forEach(name => {
                template += `${seriesName} ${name} <br />`;
            });

            return template;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
        name: 'mySeries',
    }]
};
```